# Finding all substrings and time limit exceeded error

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to find the shortest substring that includes all alphabets. I found all the substrings and checked them. It has a long runtime, and I got time limit exceeded error. I think this algorithm is not optimal.

1. If there are more effective algorithm, please teach me.
2. Why I got time limit exceeded error? I thought it is because of the nested for loop.

I have a function 'pan' to check whether the string has every alphabets or not.

```
text_list = []
len_list = []

for start in range(len(text) - 1):
    for stop in range(start + 26, len(text)):
        if pan(text[start:stop + 1]):
            text_list.append(text[start:stop + 1])
            len_list.append(len(text[start:stop + 1]))
            break # finding shortest one

if not text_list:
    result = None
else:
    # to find shortest length.
    index = len_list.index(min(len_list))
    result = text_list[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your performance problem is that for each start, for each end, you do a fresh calculation of the alphabet.  Odds are that this is already `O(n^3)` and depending on how you did `pan`, maybe worse.  Just throw it at a string with 'a' a million times in the middle, and you'll have performance problems.

Here is an alternate approach.  Keep a window and current letter count in a dictionary.  While the first letter is not needed, slide the beginning of the window forward and see if we improved.  When it is, slide the end forward.  This update is a `O(1)` each iteration, and we iterate once to put each letter into the window, and once to move it out.  Therefore this strategy is `O(n)`.

Here is code for this strategy.

```
def shortest_alphabet_substring(text, alphabet='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'):
    in_alphabet = set(list(alphabet))
    best_start = None
    best_size = None
    char_count = {}

    # Find starting window
    start = size = 0
    while size < len(text) and len(char_count) < len(in_alphabet):
        c = text[size]
        if c not in in_alphabet:
            pass
        elif c in char_count:
            char_count[c] = 1 + char_count[c]
        else:
            char_count[c] = 1
        size = size + 1

    if len(char_count) == len(alphabet):
        best_start = start
        best_size = size
        while start + size <= len(text):
            start_c = text[start]
            if start_c not in alphabet or 1 < char_count[start_c]:
                # Slide the window forward
                if start_c in alphabet:
                    char_count[start_c] = char_count[start_c] - 1
                start = start + 1
                size = size - 1
                # Did we improve on our best?
                if size < best_size:
                    best_start = start
                    best_size = size
            else:
                # widen the window
                end_c = text[start + size - 1]
                size = size + 1
                if end_c in in_alphabet:
                    char_count[end_c] = char_count[end_c] + 1
        return text[best_start: best_start + best_size]
    return None
```

Comment: When widen the window, I added "if end_c == start_now: size = size else: size = size + 1", and it works. Thank you soooooo much :)